# doing some operation on date column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table with the following columns:

personnel_id INT, date DATE, time TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE.

Every day each personnel has a clock-in and a clock-out. It's possible to have more than one clock-in and clock-out as well. For example a person may come at 8:00 and exit at 13:00, and again come back at 16:36 and clock-in and finally exit at 19:20.

So for each date I need to calculate the sum of hours a person has been present at work and from that the working hours of that person in each month. Therefore I need a select which gets a personnel_id and returns the working hours of that person in each month. for ex:

```
ID  1        2      3        4      5        6      7        8   9       10   11    12  
3   173.24   134    147.26   180    50.47    138    196.36   47  93.56   .56  78    139
```

Comment: How do you know a row in that table is a clock-in or clock-out row? What if there is no corresponding clock-out for one day?

Comment: the first time a time is registered in a day would be the clock-in. so the second time is the clock-out. if there is just one time in a day, the person has forgotten to clock-out and no time would be calculated for him in that day. assume that for 2019-01-09 the following times are registered: 08:04, 14:23, 15:46, 17:53. so these are in,out,in,out respectively. in the case 08:04, 14:23, 15:46, it would be in,out,in and so only the interval between 08:04 and 14:23 will be calculated for that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to calculate the duration for each clock-in/clock-out combination.

Assuming that you always have a even number of entries for each date for each personnel_id, you can calculate the duration for each pair with something like the following:

```
select personnel_id, 
       "date", 
       case 
         when row_number() over w % 2 = 0 then "time" - lag("time") over w
       end as duration
from person_work
window w as (partition by personnel_id, "date" order by "time")
```

`row_number()` is a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) that assigns a number to each row. `lag()` is another window function that gets the value of a column from the previous row. As both functions share the same "window definition" I only declared that once with the `window` clause at the end. The `CASE` expression calculates the difference of the `time` column for every second row. clock-in rows have an odd row number, clock-out rows have an even row number. The `% 2` checks for even row numbers.

In the next step we need to aggregate the pairs into durations per month.
This can be done by building upon the previous query. I am using a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to re-use the previous query:

```
with hours as (
  select personnel_id, 
         "date", 
         case 
           when row_number() over w % 2 = 0 then 
              -- this converts the interval into a decimal value
              extract(epoch from "time" - lag("time") over w)/3600
         end as hours
  from person_work
  window w as (partition by personnel_id, "date" order by "time")
), hours_per_month as (
  select personnel_id, 
         extract(year from "date")::int as work_year,
         extract(month from "date")::int as work_month,
         sum(hours) work_hours
  from hours
  where hours is not null
  group by personnel_id, work_year, work_month
)
select *
from hours_per_month;
```

`extract(year from ...)` returns the year of the `date` column as decimal value. `::int` is a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) that simply converts that to an integer. Strictly speaking that isn't really necessary though.

`extract(epoch from ..)` returns the duration of the [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) as seconds. Dividing that result by 3600 returns the interval as hours.

This would return something like:

```
personnel_id | work_year | work_month | work_hours
-------------+-----------+------------+-----------
           1 |      2018 |          1 |      25.33
           1 |      2018 |          2 |      17.08
           1 |      2018 |          3 |       8.25
```

Then in the final step we need turn the rows into columns. This can be done using conditional aggregation using the [filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause:

```
with hours as (
  select personnel_id, 
         "date", 
         case 
           when row_number() over w % 2 = 0 then extract(epoch from "time" - lag("time") over w)/3600
         end as hours
  from person_work
  window w as (partition by personnel_id, "date" order by "time")
), hours_per_month as (
  select personnel_id, 
         extract(year from "date")::int as work_year,
         extract(month from "date")::int as work_month,
         sum(hours) hours
  from hours
  where hours is not null
  group by personnel_id, work_year, work_month
)
select personnel_id, 
       work_year,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 1) as hours_jan,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 2) as hours_feb,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 3) as hours_mar,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 4) as hours_apr,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 5) as hours_may,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 6) as hours_jun,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 7) as hours_Jul,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 8) as hours_aug,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 9) as hours_sep,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 10) as hours_oct,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 11) as hours_nov,
       sum(hours) filter (where work_month = 12) as hours_dec
from hours_per_month
group by personnel_id, work_year;
```

This returns something like this:

```
personnel_id | work_year | hours_jan | hours_feb | hours_mar | hours_apr | hours_may | hours_jun | hours_jul | hours_aug | hours_sep | hours_oct | hours_nov | hours_dec
-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
           1 |      2018 |     25.33 |     17.08 |      8.25 |      ...  |    ...    |    ...    |    ...    |    ...    |     ....  |    ....   |     ...   |    ....
```

If you just want a report for a single year, you can use a `where work_year = ...` in the final select and remove the column from the select list and the `group by`

Online example: https://rextester.com/OEEAZ64654

Comment: there's a slight problem here. the interval between times 08:03:08 and 16:00:45 is 07:57:37. but here it returns 7.96027777777778. how can i fix it?

Comment: You can use `round()` for the decimal value

Comment: round function will turn 7.9602777777778 to 8 or to 7.9603 or whatever, which is not the actual time value that is 07:57:37. how can i calculate the exact time?

Comment: Well, your example output in the question used that format, so I assumed you want fractional hours. If you want the "raw" interval value, just remove the `extract(epoch from ..)/3600` part then you can use `to_char()` to format the interval to hours and minutes

Comment: great! but how can i do it using cross tab instead of filter?